# ffmpeg open remote video with high latency while gstreamer not

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I use MJPEG-Streamer to send my remote camera video via wifi. I use such command to see video:

gstreamer:

```
gst-launch -v souphttpsrc location= "http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream&type=.mjpg" do-timestamp=true is_live=true ! multipartdemux ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

ffmpeg:

```
 ffplay "http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream&type=.mjpg"
```

or:

```
 ffplay "http://192.168.1.1:8080/?action=stream&type=.mjpg" -fflags nobuffer
```

however the *ffplay* has a high latency up to 3~10 seconds in my test, while the *gstreamer*
show almost no latency.

when using localhost MJPEG-Streamer, both two methods show low latency. so what's the reason ? and how to decrease the latency?

more detail:

I want to use opencv to capture a remote camera,my opencv compile with ffmpeg support but without gstreamer support ( I tried but failed,the cmake seemed to not find my gstreamer,I don't know which gstreamer library to install in opensuse 13.1), I can get the video in opencv but with high latency,so I compared ffmpeg with gstreamer,the result is as above.so how to decrease the latency? I read [this link](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide#Latency),but still no solution.

thank you.

Comment: @Micka, maybe,but could you offer more infomation,I don't know how to disable FFMPEG's buffer,especially in opencv.

Comment: No idea, sorry. Maybe it isnt buffering problem at all. It was just an intuition.